# post comment to my app's Facebook page

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app that I want people to be able to post comments to the app's Facebook page.  I can post them to the person's page using

```
 FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
```

but I want to post the comments to the app's Facebook page.  Any idea of how to go about doing this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed // FYI: Posts and comments are different things. If you post to feed, you are creating posts.

Comment: I have decided to just provide a link to my app's Facebook page.  That way users can go to the page: like, follow, post and read comments by clicking on the link and going directly to the page.